# случайные неповторяющиеся числа

Tags: случайные-числа, числа

Я сгенерировала массив и случайные числа в него/

Как сделать, чтобы они не повторялись без использования других импортов, кроме рандома?

```
 Random rand = new Random();
 int r = rand.nextInt(11) + 10;
 int a= rand.nextInt(5)+2;
 int [][] array = new int [a][r];
 for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
      for (int l=0; l< r; l++ )
            array[i][l]= rand.nextInt(201)-100;
       for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){
          for (int l=0; l< r; l++ )
              System.out.print(array [i][l] +" ");
          System.out.println();
       }
```

Comment: А как бы вы вручную проверяли, что числа не повторяются? Вот точно так же и нужно сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы не проверять, было ли уже использовано очередное случайное число (что приемлемо при малых размерах, но может быть долго при большой доле использования диапазона случайных чисел), используйте [тасование Фишера-Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0)

Кроме того, в вашем коде при большой размере таблицы невозможно избежать повторов (например, pigeon hole principle не позволяет 400 мест в таблице заполнить двумястами числами без повторов), так что я уменьшил максимальный размер таблицы.

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/5DW0sg)

```
 Random rand = new Random();
 int r = rand.nextInt(11) + 10;
 int a= rand.nextInt(5)+2;  
 int [][] array = new int [r][a];   
 int [] shuf = new int [201];
 int last = 201;

 for (int i = 0; i < 201; i++)
     shuf[i] = i - 100;
 for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
      for (int l=0; l < a; l++ ) {
            int x = rand.nextInt(last);
            array[i][l] = shuf[x];
            shuf[x] = shuf[last-1];
            last--;
      }      

       for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
          for (int l=0; l< a; l++ )
              System.out.print(array [i][l] +" ");
          System.out.println();
       }    }
```

Comment: Мне для проекта нужна таблица [10,20] с случайными числами в диапазоне [-100,100]. И именно для такого размера я не знаю как сделать.

Comment: Думаю можно было бы создать массив с числами [-100,100] и, сравнив их, вывести массив с неповторяющиесями числами.

Comment: А зачем тогда случайный размер задан? Я поправил на фиксированный

Comment: Потому что суть заключается  в том что бы каждый раз получать разный массив в разными числами.

Comment: Вы уже попробовали запустить приведённый код?

Comment: Конечно и он у меня хорошо работает

Comment: Раз требуется таблица [10,20], то нужда в массиве случайного размера, я так понял, отпала?

Comment: Не совсем так, мне нужен массив случайного размера в диапазоне [10,20].

Comment: Вы прочитали мой второй абзац?

Comment: Читала. Знаю, что нужен фиксированый размер, но в задании, которое я делаю, написано так.

Comment: Дело не в фиксированном размере. Таблица 20х20 содержит 400 ячеек. А случайных чисел всего 200.

Comment: Ох, да. Простите. Я немного перепутала. Но спасибо за помощь, мне очень пригодилось.

Comment: Ещё интересует один момент, у меня в задании есть, что по диагонале этого массива должно быть случайно выводиться 1 или -1. Как лучше сделать через петлю или черз if?

Comment: А как с неповторяемостью? Приведите точное условие, отредактировав вопрос.

Comment: Уже изменила на правильное.

Comment: Можете при заполнении проверять, что попадаете на диагональ `if (i==l)`

Comment: Если вопрос исчерпан, можете пометить его как решённый